# How can a server tell what user was supplied for a domain like <user>@example.com?

Tags: domains, dns, dynamic-dns

Obviously with email protocols, the main way as far as I'm aware that addresses in the form @example.com are used, the protocol can simply provide the user part of that domain as part of the communication. But I was wondering if it's possible for a server to tell from just a ping, or HTTP request to say, bob@example.com that someone used bob. I'm leaning towards yes, because there are some examples I've seen (Dyn DNS, the company, comes to mind) of domains like foo@dyn-o-saur.com

The reason for this is that I want to be able to enable users to wake up a service and I think that this is a relatively memorable way to assign this.

I'm guessing that the server at subdomain.example.com would recieve all connections to @subdomain.example.com

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but at least "I'm guessing that the server at subdomain.example.com would recieve all connections to @subdomain.example.com" is more or less not true, it depends. For emails delivery, DNS `MX` records are consulted. If you have `subdomain.example.com MX 10 whatever.foobar.example` then all emails `@subdomain.example.com` will be sent to an host called `whatever.foobar.example`. Of course you can as well send everything to an host called `subdomain.example.com` with the proper `MX` record (or `A`/`AAAA` fallbacks but not recommended to depend on them).

Comment: "domains like foo@dyn-o-saur.com": `foo@dyn-o-saur.com` is not a domain it is an email address, `dyn-o-saur.com` is a domain. It is probably why I do not understand your question as you seem to mix email addresses and domains (but in all cases, you can safely remove "ping" or HTTP from the equation, neither mixes with emails or domains)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I must have misread earlier. I believe foo.dyn-o-saur.com is what I actually saw.